# Codename One background service

Tags: java, codenameone

I would want to constantly check for new SMS from a background service (which suns even if application is stopped).
I wonder if Codename One supports background services as Android platform supports https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One supports services using [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) on Android. Other platforms don't have anything quite like Android's services so this isn't something that can be generalized at that level.

iOS/Windows Phone do not allow intercepting SMS's and Android itself has made significant changes to incoming SMS logic which restrict this functionality significantly so either way this isn't something you should do. Generally the recommended way to handle incoming wakeup is to use push notification.